# Matlab subclassing question

Tags: oop, matlab

Question about subclassing in matlab, under the new class system. I've got class A with some protected properties:

```
classdef Table < Base

properties (SetAccess = protected, GetAccess = public)
    PropA = [];
end %properties
```

I'd like to make a subclass with some specialized features, and further restrict access to PropA.  (i.e. make get access private in the subclass).  My first thought was:

```
classdef subTable < Table

...
methods (Access = private)
    out = get.PropA(obj, value);
end %private methods
```

However, in the help it says: "You must define property access methods in a methods block that specifies no attributes."  So much for that idea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. From [MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brenyev-1.html#zmw57dd0e11935):

There are only two conditions that allow you to redefine superclass properties:

- The superclass property Abstract attribute is set to true
- The superclass property has both the SetAccess and GetAccess attributes set to private

Nor do I think that doing this would be a good idea. It violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Functions written to accept a Table should also be able to accept a subTable and work properly. If such a function accessed PropA, it would fail when passed a subTable.